# SDL OpenGL Textures Lost

Tags: c++, opengl, gcc, rendering, sdl

I have a fully working engine that is using SDL and OpenGL. I have a textured box on my OpenGL/SDL screen - however when I try to change the video mode (e.g. toggle fullscreen with F11) the texturing is lost (the box is just plain white), if I toggle back to windowed mode the box is still white (with the textured image lost). Does this mean I cannot change my video mode in the middle of the application (e.g. toggle fullscreen) or does it mean I have to reload my OGL textures every time I do so?

Some extra notes: I am using CodeBlocks with MinGW on windows 7, the libraries I have linked are: SOIL (a library for easily loading textures in OGL - http://www.lonesock.net/soil.html), OpenGL32, Glu32 and SDL.

I have some images to demonstrate my problem (the first one is windowed mode and the second one is when I *try* to change to fullscreen with a call to SDL_SetVideoMode(...) - SDL_WM_ToggleFullScreen doesn't work.

[image: Windowed mode (this is how I want it to look):]

[image: Fullscreen mode (the texturing is lost!!!):]

Answer (score 2):

> I have a textured box on my OpenGL/SDL screen - however when I try to change the video mode (e.g. toggle fullscreen with F11) the texturing is lost (the box is just plain white), if I toggle back to windowed mode the box is still white (with the textured image lost). Does this mean I cannot change my video mode in the middle of the application (e.g. toggle fullscreen) or does it mean I have to reload my OGL textures every time I do so?

It strongly depends on how the used framework implements video mode changes.

In general when deleting an OpenGL context all it's associated data is lost, *except* if there's another OpenGL context with which a "sharing" has been established. That can be used to keep all uploaded data persistent between context recreation. However a mere video mode change usually doesn't require a context recreation, and usually also not a window recreation.

However the framework used by you (SDL) will completely clean up a window and the context when changing the video mode, thus loosing you the loaded resources. Unstable development versions of SDL have better OpenGL support, allowing for video mode changes without context teardown inbetween.

Comment: I have switched to SDL 2.0 (SDL 1.2 which I was using is old) but I have yet to see if that would fix up the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the problem stems from the way SDL recreates the window. I had this problem before and the solution for me was to set up a special uninitialize and initialize function that only got rid of/created images.

Essentially, when SDL's Resize event is called (http://www.libsdl.org/docs/html/sdlresizeevent.html) you would uninitialize any artistic assets required and then re-initialize them after entering or leaving fullscreen.